# How To Quickly Remove Access To A SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, read-only

Sometimes we have a requirement to stop users from accessing a SharePoint Online site.  For example, if there's an issue with data and we want a stable/non-changing site to work with we would like to stop users from accessing sites (Site Collections and/or sub sites) for a period of time while work is completed.

We could remove all users permissions from a site but that is a lot of work and then we have to reinstate the permissions exactly as before.

In on-premises scenarios we could put a Site Collection into read-only mode but that is not available to us in SharePoint Online.

Are there options available to us out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a Site Collection in read only mode in ReadOnly, by using a Site policy in Site Collection Administration (Site Setting). It is not the fast approach, but possably better than revoking user access.

See [HOW TO MAKE SHAREPOINT ONLINE SITE COLLECTION READ ONLY](https://www.anupams.net/make-sharepoint-online-site-collection-read-only/)

It's a little work, but most of it can be done in advance.